# MVVM - Get property of ViewModel from seperate Command class

Tags: c#, mvvm

Thanks in advance for helphing me.

I develop for the first time in MVVM and I woul'd like to seperate the business logic of the *view model* in two class, **MyViewViewModel** and **MyViewCommand**.

Actually, I use a RelayCommand for bind the commands in the view model.

**MyViewCommandHandler:**

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Constructor
    /// </summary>
    public ConfigRefCommandHandler(Action requestClose)
    {
        base.RequestClose += requestClose;
        // Assign all operations to commands
        // Config
        this.CmdSelectAllReferences = new RelayCommand(this.SelectAllReferencesCmd, this.CanExecuteSelectAllReferencesCmd);
        this.CmdModifyDetails = new RelayCommand(this.ModifyDetailsCmd, this.CanExecuteModifyDetailsCmd);
        this.CmdProhibitPlanning = new RelayCommand(this.ProhibitPlannningCmd, this.CanExecuteProhibitPlannningCmd);
        this.CmdExit = new RelayCommand(this.ExitCmd, this.CanExecuteExitCmd);
        // Macro
        this.CmdAddMacro = new RelayCommand(this.AddMacroCmd, this.CanExecuteAddMacroCmd);
        this.CmdModMacro = new RelayCommand(this.ModMacroCmd, this.CanExecuteModMacroCmd);
        this.CmdDelMacro = new RelayCommand(this.DelMacroCmd, this.CanExecuteDelMacroCmd);
        // Program
        this.CmdAddProgram = new RelayCommand(this.AddProgramCmd, this.CanExecuteAddProgramCmd);
        this.CmdModProgram = new RelayCommand(this.ModProgramCmd, this.CanExecuteModProgramCmd);
        this.CmdDelProgram = new RelayCommand(this.DelProgramCmd, this.CanExecuteDelProgramCmd);
    }
```

**MyViewViewModel:**

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Internal reference
    /// </summary>
    public String InternalReference
    {
        get
        {
            return "test";
        }
        set
        {
            base.OnPropertyChanged("InternalReference");
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Constructor
    /// </summary>
    public ConfigRefViewModel(Action requestClose)
    {
        ConfigRefCommandHandler commandHandler = new ConfigRefCommandHandler(requestClose);

        // Config
        this.CmdSelectAllReferences = commandHandler.CmdSelectAllReferences;
        this.CmdModifyDetails = commandHandler.CmdModifyDetails;
        this.CmdProhibitPlanning = commandHandler.CmdProhibitPlanning;
        this.CmdExit = commandHandler.CmdExit;
        // Macro
        this.CmdAddMacro = commandHandler.CmdAddMacro;
        this.CmdModMacro = commandHandler.CmdModMacro;
        this.CmdDelMacro = commandHandler.CmdDelMacro;
        // Program
        this.CmdAddProgram = commandHandler.CmdAddProgram;
        this.CmdModProgram = commandHandler.CmdModProgram;
        this.CmdDelProgram = commandHandler.CmdDelProgram;
    }
```

How can I pass **MyViewViewModel** into **MyViewCommand** to set the **InternalReference** property to activate the **OnPropertyChanged()** method to reload **MyView** ?

Comment: I don't know why I can't add "Hello" to my post !

**Hello everybody**. :)

Comment: To answer your comment, since SO is a question & answer site, conversational phrases like "Hello", "Thanks", etc... are not necessary and just add "unnecessary noise" (so to speak) to the text body of the question. That said: Hello!

Comment: With regard to your question: Since you use RelayCommands (which essentially just house delegates), why would you need to pass the VM to the command? Just create the VM-specific command instances (the fact that you want to pass the VM to the command indicates the commands being VM-specific) within the VM itself, using a method of the VM as the command's delegate. If that is not possible/undesired, please explain what are the needs/requirments/constraints that prevent you from doing that...

Comment: Okay :) If I understand what you want to say to me. I can use the commands on VM to update the properties ? I want it ! But I don't how can I make it .. Can you put me an exemple please ?

Comment: But I don't want command in VM because the "commands" is my business logic and I woul'd like seperate the VM (for me, is just "PropertyChanged") of the logcig (commands).

Comment: I think I can create commands and inherit it for VM. That permise the seperation of my VM and Commands in differents class. No ? It's bad design no ? :/

Comment: Glad you found an approach that works for you. Just a comment about you saying "_commands is_ (part of?) _my business logic and would separate them from VM_".. Not sure if you were misunderstanding the concept of Commands, or i am misunderstanding your comment. Anyway, Commands are not part of the business logic/data model. Commands are part of the interaction logic ("interaction model"). (It is the purpose of view models to specify/implement the interaction logic that is related to features/functionality of your program... :)

Comment: Tell me if I'm doing things wrong. My **MyViewViewModel** only contains my properties used by the **View**. My **MyViewCommand** class contains the actions to be performed. In its actions there is the connection to the services that will retrieve *information, ObservableCollection, bool, string...etc...* from the database. Once this *data/objects* are retrieved, the **MyViewCommand** class organizes the information to update the properties of the **MyViewViewModel**. Since **MyViewViewModel** is linked to the **View**, updating a property calls **OnPropertyChanged** to update the **View**.

Comment: Sounds okay. If it works, it is not wrong :) Whether the details of your approach are a good fit for the structure of your program i obviously cannot tell, but from a general point of view it is alright...

Answer (score 0):

Finally I have used another class for getting all **ViewModel**.

This class is a **Static** class ans she use a **Singleton** pattern, as you can see:

```
/// <summary>
/// View model handler for all ViewModel
/// </summary>
static class ViewModelHandler
{
    #region Properties
    /// <summary>
    /// Config reference ViewModel
    /// </summary>
    private static ConfigRefViewModel ConfigRefViewModel = null;
    #endregion

    #region Getter
    /// <summary>
    /// Get the ConfigRefViewModel property
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="requestClose">The request for closing view</param>
    /// <returns>The view model of config reference view</returns>
    public static ConfigRefViewModel GetConfigRefViewModel(Action requestClose = null)
    {
        if (ViewModelHandler.ConfigRefViewModel != null) return ViewModelHandler.ConfigRefViewModel;

        ViewModelHandler.SetConfigRefViewModel(new ConfigRefViewModel());
        ViewModelHandler.GetConfigRefViewModel().Initialize(requestClose);

        return ViewModelHandler.ConfigRefViewModel;
    }
    #endregion

    #region Setter
    /// <summary>
    /// Set the ConfigRefViewModel property
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="configRefViewModel">ConfigRefViewModel to set</param>
    private static void SetConfigRefViewModel(ConfigRefViewModel configRefViewModel) => ViewModelHandler.ConfigRefViewModel = configRefViewModel;
    #endregion
}
```

To make it work, I have removed the constructor of the **ConfigRefViewModel** and put it in an initializing method because in this constructor, the **ConfigRefCommand** class is instanciate.

It was a problem because the **ConfigRefCommand** class need the method to close the view, while my **ViewModelHandler** needed to instantiate an empty **ConfigRefViewModel** in first.